how to sticky tooltip in Amcharts5 in react?
i want to use tooltip in my react app, and i want this tooltip to always be present in every point chart
im use Amchart5 and reactJs
i want like this =>
enter image description here
and when I use this in codepen it works but when I use the same code in react it doesn't work

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
